# Change the format of file path which is partitioned by java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: scala, apache-spark, timestamp

We are using spark as a data processing platform and Scala programming language. When we write data on storage account(ADLS gen 2), we partition the data by datetime column which is of type java.sql.Timestamp. We write the data using spark dataframe.write operation

By default, it creates following path on storage account and writes parquet files in it

Path - `__datetime=a/b/c/yyyy-MM-dd HH%3Amm%3Ass`

The problem is, it has encoded : but not space and because the URL is not fully encoded, it creates problems for us. Is there a  fix to this problem?

Can I change the format of a column(of type java.sql.Timestamp), so that the output file path looks like this which does not have any encoding?

```
__datetime=a/b/c/yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss
```

or

```
__datetime=a/b/c/yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm_ss
```

Is it possible to do this within java.sql.Timestamp object and without converting it to a string?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the name / type dataframe column with a simple select + alias.

The encoding is necessary, though because file paths cannot have `:` characters, but they can have spaces... Unclear why you need full URL encoding

Comment: we don't want to remove the the partition column and I have updated my post for that. We just want to change the path format. Is it possible to do it without changing the type of the column?

Comment: I meant hide, rather than remove. For example `/path/to/data/files.ext` vs `/path/to/data/partition=X/files.ext`... Because then there would be no partition. In any case, you cannot reformat a timestamp object without parsing and reformatting as a string. I'm not sure why you don't want to use a string

Comment: We can use string. I was just curious

Comment: You _can use_ timestamp fields. You'll just need to use [`date_format`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/sql/index.html#date_format) for example to convert to a string